# Why is the log taken in the formula for weight of evidence?

Tags: classification, information-theory, propensity-scores

Why is the logarithm used when calculating the [weight of evidence](http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=WeightofEvidence/WeightofEvidenceWOEIntroductoryOverview) (WOE)? For example, let bin i ($B_i$) have,

- 15% good
- 30% bad

So good/bad = 0.5. Namely for each bad item there are 0.5 good in $B_i$. That is very clear. However, why is the logarithm taken of that $\log(\rm good/bad)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because it then provides an input to logistic regression:so you get back p(good) as an output. Ie you use logistic regression to combine univariate odds estimates. If you have a single WOE input variable you get back the corresponding p(good) from logistic regression, but the aim is to create an combined estimate using all the factors (gender, age bucket etc). It's not how I would create a multivariate prediction (since you are averaging univariate estimates) but I guess the idea is  to develop an understandable prediction.